# How to forward HttpServletRequest data second time to REST controller using Spring Interceptor?

Tags: spring, servlets, interceptor, servlet-filters

**Step 1:**

Read HttpServletRequest data in preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler){} like below

```
@Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {        
                ServletContext query = request.getServletContext();
            BufferedReader br = request.getReader();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String s = "";
            while((s = br.readLine())!=null) {
                sb.append(s);
            }
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
   return true;
}
```

**Step 2:**
once preHandle(request, response) method job completed then request control reached to Rest Controller so here Request body is null

```
@PostMapping(value = "/addOrRemoveCustomer", produces = { "application/json" }, consumes = {"application/json" })
    public ResponseEntity<Object> addOrRemoveCustomer(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> requestBody) {
        logger.debug("addOrRemoveCustomer : addOrRemoveCustomer() start....");
        Object requestData = null;

        try {
            requestData = customerService.addOrRemoveCustomer(requestBody);
        } catch (BusinessException e) {
            BusinessException businessException = new BusinessException(e);
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(businessException.getErrorResponse(),
                    Utils.getHttpStatus(e.getErrorCode()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            BusinessException businessException = new BusinessException(
                    "Error in addOrRemoveCustomer service get call", e);
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(businessException.getErrorResponse(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        logger.debug("addOrRemoveCustomer Contoller : addOrRemoveCustomer() end...");
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(requestData, Utils.getHttpStatus("200"));
    }
```

In Rest controller, requestData getting null because already requestData was read in interceptor(`BufferedReader br = request.getReader();`) so now it is required to read Request body data again in Rest controller ?

How to achieve above requirement?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Once a HttpRequest has been read as an input stream (BufferedReader) this stream is closed. Then, Spring cannot extract data from stream request.

If you want to log the request data try to use the CommonsRequestLoggingFilter. You can view how use this filter on the following url: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging

Comment: Thanks for your help. Limitation

ContentCachingRequestWrapper class only supports the following:
1.Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
2.Method-Type:POST but I am looking Content-Type:application/json

Comment: Then, rather than get an input stream from request, you could call to following methods of HttpServletRequest to get parameters values, path, etc.:  getParamterMap, getServletPath, getRequestURI, getRequestURL